# Fourier series with "Riemann" coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series, riemann-zeta

Consider the sum (which is a Fourier series and a Dirichlet series):

$$F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-s} \cos(2 \pi n x)$$

For $\Re(s)>1$ we have (thanks to absolute convergence) $\lim_{x \to 0} F(x)=\zeta(s)$ but does this holds for $0<\Re(s)<1$ ?

I am sure this is more than well known but I did not find it on internet, and as a simple Poisson summation formula does not answer the question, it is not completely easy, any reference ?

Comment: The difficulty here is that the zeta function isn't given by it's Dirichlet series representation over for real parts between $0$ and $1$. Rather its values are obtained via analytic continuation.

Comment: Yes, that is why I note $\zeta(s)$. $F(x)$ is well defined even for $0<\Re(s)<1$ when $x>0$ so what is the limit for $x \to 0$ in this case, do we still have this limit equal to $\zeta(s)$ by analytic continuation ?

Comment: The answer I posted was nonsense. Do you have some reason to think that $\lim_{x\to0}F(x)$ _exists_ when $0<\Re s<1$?

Comment: Analytic continuation may be ? If the limit does not exist then the queston is what is the asymptotic ? It is in litterature, for sure but I am not a professional and did not find it !

Comment: @Bertrand After spending days on this problem, I found that the limit as $x\rightarrow 0+$ does not exist. But, this reference has much more information about polylogarithms, it contains a series expansion of $\sum \frac{e^{\mu}}{n^s}$ with $|\mu|<2\pi$ : http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/pubs/1992/110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We shall see that the limit of $F(x)$ does not exist as $x\rightarrow 0^+$ for $0<s<1$. The following lemma follows from $$\cos(2\pi nx)\sin \pi x = \frac12 \left[ \sin \pi x(2n+1)-\sin \pi x(2n-1)\right]$$
and the telescoping sum.

**Lemma 1**

> Let $t\ge 1$ and $x>0$. Then 
>   $$
> A_t=\sum_{n\leq t} \cos (2\pi n x)  =\frac{\sin\pi x(2\lfloor t\rfloor +1)-\sin\pi x}{2\sin \pi x}.
> $$

By partial summation, we have

**Lemma 2**

> Let $x>0$ and $0<s<1$. Then
>   $$
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos 2\pi nx}{n^s}=s\int_1^{\infty} \frac{A_t}{t^{s+1}}dt=-\frac12+s\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\sin\pi x(2\lfloor t\rfloor +1)}{2t^{s+1}\sin \pi x} dt.
> $$

We replace $\sin\pi x(2\lfloor t \rfloor +1)$ by $\sin 2\pi x t$ at a cost of a uniformly bounded function. By change of variable $x t = u$, we have

**Lemma 3**

> Let $x>0$ and $0<s<1$. Then there are uniformly bounded functions $B_1(s,x)$ and $B_2(s,x)$  such that 
>   $$
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos 2\pi nx}{n^s}=B_1(s,x)+\frac s{1-s}B_2(s,x)+\frac{x^s}{2\sin \pi x} s\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin 2\pi u}{u^{s+1}}du.$$

By the integral in this post: [I'm looking for several ways to prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty }\sin(x)x^mdx=\cos(\frac{\pi m}{2})\Gamma (m+1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437582/im-looking-for-several-ways-to-prove-that-int-0-infty-sinxxmdx-cos/437761#437761)

we have an expression for the integral.

**Lemma 4**

> For $0<s<1$, we have
>   $$
> s\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin 2\pi u}{u^{s+1}}du=(2\pi)^s \Gamma(1-s)\sin \frac{\pi s}2
> $$

Back to the main problem, we have

**Theorem**

> For $x>0$ and $0<s<1$, and the uniformly bounded functions $B_i(s,x)$ the same as above lemma, we have
>   $$
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos 2\pi nx}{n^s}=B_1(s,x)+\frac s{1-s}B_2(s,x) + \frac{x^s}{2\sin \pi x} (2\pi)^s \Gamma(1-s)\sin \frac{\pi s}2.
> $$

Therefore, for a fixed $0<s<1$, the limit of $F(x)$ as $x\rightarrow 0^+$ does not exist.